# $\operatorname{Hom}(F,R)$ is torsion free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $F$ be a free $R$-module where $R$ is PID. Then $\operatorname{Hom}(F,R)$ is torsion free.

Writing $F = \bigoplus_{i\in I}R$, I'm not sure $\operatorname{Hom}(\bigoplus_{i\in I}R,R)\simeq\bigoplus_{i\in I}\operatorname{Hom}(R,R)$. How can I prove this?

Comment: The true isomorphism would be $\hom(\bigoplus_{i\in I}R,R)\cong \prod_{i\in I}\hom(R,R)$. I don't see excactly how that is related to being torsion-free, but it wasn't my idea.

Comment: Isn't $\mathrm{Hom}(R,R)\simeq R$ and then the direct product is torsion-free?

Comment: This is true and has nothing to do with $F$ being free or not (it also doesn't require $R$ to be anything more than an integral domain). Have you tried just checking this by definition?